# Are squash-merges compatible with the Developer Certificate of Origin?

Tags: licensing, git

The [Developer Certificate of Origin](https://developercertificate.org/) appears to be widely used in open source at this point, including support at [GitHub](https://github.com/apps/dco/) and use by [GitLab community edition](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/11/01/gitlab-switches-to-dco-license/).

In accepting a pull request, many folks (including me) like to use a "squash" merge where all commits are concatenated into a single commit. But then, this isn't *exactly* what the contributor signed, and the person merging the pull request gets write access to the combined commit message.

So does the DCO make it impossible to do squash-and-merge?

Comment: So this Developer Certificate of Origin thing is just a text document?  No digital signatures or anything like that?  How could it possibly make a technical maneuver like a "squash and merge" impossible?

Comment: Is the result of the squash merge the same?  In other words, is the contribution in whole applied as provided?  If so, I believe that would fall within the spirit of the Development Certificate of Origin's purpose.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you type your name into a web form, it's a valid signature (but IANAL!). If I change the submission data, did you still sign the result?

Comment: So to be clear, I mean legally possible. Or perhaps just "legal."

Comment: For that, you need to talk to our [legal department](https://law.stackexchange.com/).